# How to remove vertical dashed lines

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the lines shown in this screenshot?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: At least add tags to your question...

Comment: are you using resharper?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove vertical dotted indentation lines in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763074/remove-vertical-dotted-indentation-lines-in-visual-studio-2017) -- This question is older, but according to [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/184684), "*The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate.*"

Answer (score 2):

For me I was using Visual Studio 2017 Professional and wanted to get rid of these as well. I was able to find the setting here:

`Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> General --> UNCHECK Show structure guide lines`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you have ProductivityPowerTools installed .

```
Go to Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Other Extensions -->Structure visualizer options--> Uncheck Show code structure in editor.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish by click on **View Indent Guides** on the following path.

```
Edit-->Advanced-->View Indent Guides
```