# Remove vertical dotted indentation lines in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've just installed Visual Studio 2017 and got strange vertical indentation marks in code editor.

[image]

How can I remove them?

P.S. I disabled all extensions but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the last version of Visual Studio Code, downloaded in July/2017 (please note that this is not Visual Studio, but as @tambre pointed out, this may help in VS too), the name of this setting changed:

Go to the menu Code->Preference->Settings and search for "renderIndentGuides". The complete setting should appear as:

```
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

Change it to false and that's it.

Comment: on the new version only this will work, it doesn't even have a Tools option

Comment: this made me so happy :D I tried to find it for a while and now here it was.

Comment: This worked for mac. Just added it and set it to FALSE. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks mate this made my day using a plugged external monitor. I removed it because it doesn't align well.

Answer (score 265):

There is an option under `Tools → Options → Text Editor` called `Show structure guide lines` that should remove that.

Comment: Just if you want to 'reduce' the impact of them (I did) - Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> (Show settings for: Text Editor) -> 'Structure Guide Lines' and you can change the colour.

Comment: When I disabled that, my world came back into focus.

Comment: Many thanks...I am sure it helps some, but it was distracting to me

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I set mine to (243, 243, 243), almost white, but just barely visible. -- It's way less distracting now. :)

Comment: what about for MAC?

Comment: For anyone interested: on Mac (VSC v.1.49), the option is called `Render Indent Guide` under Text Editor in Settings.

Comment: Hard to find when using localized versions of Visual Studio, italian is "Mostra guide per strutture"

Comment: If the option config above not help, it may be caused by some extension tools like Resharper

Answer (score 12):

Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> and it will be removed.

Comment: This removes horizontal dotted lines for indentation, setting is `Edit.ViewWhiteSpace - Text Editor - Ctrl+E ,Ctrl+S` as shown on FeinCtrl

Answer (score 4):

The same thing in VS2019 is called `Show guides for declaration level constructs` in the section of `Tools` → `Options` → `Block Structure Guides`; you might want to uncheck `Show guides for code level constructs` as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's been mentioned in a comment, so I'm just bringing this up as an alternative answer: you can change the color of the vertical dotted lines. They are called "**Structure Guide Lines**" in the Visual Studio Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors dialog. I set mine to { 55, 55, 55} so they are barely visible on the dark-mode background.

Another related setting is "**Visible White Space**" color, which I set to { 13, 52, 60} after activating the Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W) option.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings->Text editor -> Editor>Guideline:indentation -> uncheck

Answer (score 0):

A slight update for those using Visual Studio Code, version 1.48.1 (2020-08-19) on Windows 10.

1. Go to the Settings: `Ctrl`+`,` OR `File` => `Preferences` => `Settings`
2. Search for `renderindent`
3. Toggle the settings checkbox for `Editor: Render Indent Guides`